# Almacenar un dato retornado por un Listener de Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

El problema es que no sé cómo almacenar un `int` que me devuelve el método `count1()`.

Este método usa un listener de Firebase que hace un `count` sobre la base de datos y retorna el resultado.

Este método lo tengo que llamar varias veces con datos distintos y debo almacenar esos números para más tarde operar con ellos.

Lo que pasa es que al ser asíncronos no me devuelve nada si estoy fuera de ese listener.

El código es Java para la plataforma Android:

```
public static void actualizarCombiAJugar() {
 int n1 = database.count1("N1", combi.getN1());

        numMax1.put(combi.getN1(), n1);
        posiciones.put(1, numMax1);
        ////////// N1 ////////

       
        int n2 = database.count1("N2", combi.getN2());

        numMax2.put(combi.getN2(), n2);
        posiciones.put(2, numMax2);

        ////////// N2 /////////

       
        int n3 = database.count1("N3", combi.getN3());

        numMax4.put(combi.getN3(), n3);
        posiciones.put(3, numMax4);

}




public static int count1(String num, int n) {


    db.collection("combinaciones")
            .whereEqualTo(num, n)
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    Map<String, Object> comb = new HashMap<>();

                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        int cont = 0;

                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            contador = document.getData();
                            cont++;//devolver esta variable
                        }

                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });

    return cont;
}
```

Ésta es la clase completa:

```
public class database {
    Context context;
    static FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    static final Map<Integer, Map<String, Object>> combi = new HashMap<>();
    static Map<String, Object> contador = new HashMap<>();
    public static HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Integer>> posiciones = new HashMap();
    public static int max = -9999;
    private static DatabaseReference dbCombi;
    public ArrayList<combinacion> array = new ArrayList<>();


    public database(@Nullable Context context) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
    }


    public void inicializarCombPosibles(combinacion comb) {
        db.collection("comb_posibles")
                .document("combGana")
                .set(comb);
    }

    public void inicializarCombinaciones(combinacion comb) {
        db.collection("combinaciones")
                .add(comb);
                /*.set(/*new combinacion(2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), SetOptions.merge()comb
                );*/
    }


    public void dameCombinacionGanadora() {
        dbCombi = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("comb_posibles");
        dbCombi.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);

        /*DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("comb_posibles").document("combGana");
        docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                    if (document.exists()) {
                        data = document.getData();
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
                    }

                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
                }
            }

        });*/
    }

    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            //  MainActivity.array.clear();
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                for (DataSnapshot snap : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    combinacion comb = snap.getValue(combinacion.class);
                    //MainActivity.array.add(comb);
                }
                MainActivity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

        }
    };

    private static void mostrarData(MainAdapter.ViewHolder holder, Map<String, Object> c) {
        combinacion combina = new combinacion();
        combina.setN1(Math.toIntExact((Long) c.get("n1")));
        combina.setN2(Math.toIntExact((Long) c.get("n2")));
        combina.setN3(Math.toIntExact((Long) c.get("n3")));
        combina.setN4(Math.toIntExact((Long) c.get("n4")));
        combina.setN5(Math.toIntExact((Long) c.get("n5")));
        combina.setES1(Math.toIntExact((Long) c.get("es1")));
        combina.setES2(Math.toIntExact((Long) c.get("es2")));

        MainAdapter.personalizaVista(holder, combina);
    }

    public static void dameCombinaciones() {
        db.collection("combinaciones")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {

                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            int cont = 0;
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {

                                Map<String, Object> data = document.getData();
                                combi.put(cont, data);
                                Log.w(TAG, "Bucle", task.getException());
                                cont++;

                            }
                            readData(combi);
                        } else {
                            Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private static void readData(Map<Integer, Map<String, Object>> combi) {
        actualizarCombiAJugar();
        actualizaBd();
    }

    public static void actualizarCombiAJugar() {
        // database.dameCombinaciones();
        Map<Integer, Map<String, Object>> cursor = combi;


        HashMap<Integer, Integer> numMax1 = new HashMap();
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> numMax2 = new HashMap();
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> numMax4 = new HashMap();
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> numMax5 = new HashMap();
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> numMax6 = new HashMap();
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> numMax7 = new HashMap();
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> numMax8 = new HashMap();
        int n = 0;

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Map<String, Object>> c : cursor.entrySet()) {
            combinacion combi = new combinacion();

            combi.setN1(Math.toIntExact((Long) c.getValue().get("n1")));
            combi.setN2(Math.toIntExact((Long) c.getValue().get("n2")));
            combi.setN3(Math.toIntExact((Long) c.getValue().get("n3")));
            combi.setN4(Math.toIntExact((Long) c.getValue().get("n4")));
            combi.setN5(Math.toIntExact((Long) c.getValue().get("n5")));
            combi.setES1(Math.toIntExact((Long) c.getValue().get("es1")));
            combi.setES2(Math.toIntExact((Long) c.getValue().get("es2")));

            //combinacion combi1 = MainActivity.adapter.lugarCombinacion(n);
            int n1 = database.count1("N1", combi.getN1());

            numMax1.put(combi.getN1(), n1);
            posiciones.put(1, numMax1);
            ////////// N1 ////////

            //combinacion combi2 = MainActivity.adapter.lugarCombinacion(n);
            int n2 = database.count1("N2", combi.getN2());

            numMax2.put(combi.getN2(), n2);
            posiciones.put(2, numMax2);

            ////////// N2 /////////

            //combinacion combi3 = MainActivity.adapter.lugarCombinacion(n);
            int n3 = database.count1("N3", combi.getN3());

            numMax4.put(combi.getN3(), n3);
            posiciones.put(3, numMax4);

            ////////// N3 /////////

            //combinacion combi4 = MainActivity.adapter.lugarCombinacion(n);
            int n4 = database.count1("N4", combi.getN4());

            numMax5.put(combi.getN4(), n4);
            posiciones.put(4, numMax5);

            ////////// N4 /////////


            //combinacion combi5 = MainActivity.adapter.lugarCombinacion(n);
            int n5 = database.count1("N5", combi.getN5());

            numMax6.put(combi.getN5(), n5);
            posiciones.put(5, numMax6);

            ////////// N5 /////////


            //combinacion combi6 = MainActivity.adapter.lugarCombinacion(n);
            int n6 = database.count1("es1", combi.getES1());

            numMax7.put(combi.getES1(), n6);
            posiciones.put(6, numMax7);

            ////////// N6 /////////

            //combinacion combi7 = MainActivity.adapter.lugarCombinacion(n);
            int n7 = database.count1("es2", combi.getES2());

            numMax8.put(combi.getES2(), n7);
            posiciones.put(7, numMax8);

            ////////// N7 /////////
            n++;

        }
    }

    public static void actualizaBd() {
        int pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0, pos5 = 0, pos6 = 0, pos7 = 0;
        int cont = 0;
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Integer>> posi : posiciones.entrySet()) {
            cont++;
            int clavepos = posi.getKey();
            HashMap<Integer, Integer> num = posi.getValue();
            max = -9999;
            for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> n : num.entrySet()) {
                int claveN = n.getKey();
                int valor = n.getValue();

                if (clavepos == 1) {
                    if (valor > max) {
                        max = valor;
                        pos1 = claveN;
                    }
                } else if (clavepos == 2) {
                    if (valor > max) {
                        max = valor;
                        pos2 = claveN;
                    }
                } else if (clavepos == 3) {
                    if (valor > max) {
                        max = valor;
                        pos3 = claveN;
                    }
                } else if (clavepos == 4) {
                    if (valor > max) {
                        max = valor;
                        pos4 = claveN;
                    }
                } else if (clavepos == 5) {
                    if (valor > max) {
                        max = valor;
                        pos5 = claveN;
                    }
                } else if (clavepos == 6) {
                    if (valor > max) {
                        max = valor;
                        pos6 = claveN;
                    }
                } else if (clavepos == 7) {
                    if (valor > max) {
                        max = valor;
                        pos7 = claveN;
                    }
                }
            } // for

        } // for
        actualiza(pos1, pos2, pos3, pos4, pos5, pos6, pos7);

        MainActivity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public static void actualiza(int pos1, int pos2, int pos3, int pos4, int pos5, int pos6, int pos7) {
        DocumentReference dR = db.collection("comb_posibles").document("combGana");
        dR.update("n1", pos1, "n2", pos2, "n3", pos3, "n4", pos4, "n5", pos5, "es1", pos6, "es2", pos7)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully updated!");
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Error updating document", e);
                    }
                });
    }

    public static void contarCombinaciones(VisualizarCombinacionesActivity vCA) {
        db.collection("combinaciones")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        List<Object> data = new ArrayList<>();
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            int cont = 0;
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                data.add(document.getData());
                                cont++;
                            }
                            vCA.adaptador(cont, data);
                        } else {
                            Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    public static int count1(String num, int n) {


        db.collection("combinaciones")
                .whereEqualTo(num, n)
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        Map<String, Object> comb = new HashMap<>();

                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            int cont = 0;

                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                contador = document.getData();
                                cont++;//devolver esta variable
                            }

                        } else {
                            Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });

        return cont;
    }

    public void insertar(combinacion combi) {
        db.collection("combinaciones")
                .add(combi);
    }
}
```

---

Usando el código de su respuesta quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
 public static void actualizarCombiAJugar() {
    // database.dameCombinaciones();
    Map<Integer, Map<String, Object>> cursor = combi;


    HashMap<Integer, Integer> numMax1 = new HashMap();
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> numMax2 = new HashMap();
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> numMax3 = new HashMap();
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> numMax4 = new HashMap();
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> numMax5 = new HashMap();
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> numMax6 = new HashMap();
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> numMax7 = new HashMap();
    int n = 0;

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Map<String, Object>> c : cursor.entrySet()) {
        combinacion combi = new combinacion();

        combi.setN1(Math.toIntExact((Long) c.getValue().get("n1")));
        combi.setN2(Math.toIntExact((Long) c.getValue().get("n2")));
        combi.setN3(Math.toIntExact((Long) c.getValue().get("n3")));
        combi.setN4(Math.toIntExact((Long) c.getValue().get("n4")));
        combi.setN5(Math.toIntExact((Long) c.getValue().get("n5")));
        combi.setES1(Math.toIntExact((Long) c.getValue().get("es1")));
        combi.setES2(Math.toIntExact((Long) c.getValue().get("es2")));

        ////////// N1 ////////
        /* Parte síncrona */
        database.count1("N1", combi.getN1(), new RetrollamadaContInterface() {
            @Override
            public void onContObtenido(int n1) {
                /* Parte asíncrona */
                numMax1.put(combi.getN1(), n1);
                posiciones.put(1, numMax1);
            }
        });

        ////////// N2 ////////
        /* Parte síncrona */
        database.count1("N2", combi.getN2(), new RetrollamadaContInterface() {
            @Override
            public void onContObtenido(int n2) {
                /* Parte asíncrona */
                numMax2.put(combi.getN2(), n2);
                posiciones.put(2, numMax2);
            }
        });

        ////////// N3 ////////
        /* Parte síncrona */
        database.count1("N3", combi.getN3(), new RetrollamadaContInterface() {
            @Override
            public void onContObtenido(int n3) {
                /* Parte asíncrona */
                numMax3.put(combi.getN3(), n3);
                posiciones.put(3, numMax3);
            }
        });

        ////////// N4 ////////
        /* Parte síncrona */
        database.count1("N4", combi.getN4(), new RetrollamadaContInterface() {
            @Override
            public void onContObtenido(int n4) {
                /* Parte asíncrona */
                numMax4.put(combi.getN4(), n4);
                posiciones.put(4, numMax4);
            }
        });

        ////////// N5 ////////
        /* Parte síncrona */
        database.count1("N5", combi.getN5(), new RetrollamadaContInterface() {
            @Override
            public void onContObtenido(int n5) {
                /* Parte asíncrona */
                numMax5.put(combi.getN5(), n5);
                posiciones.put(5, numMax5);
            }
        });

        ////////// ES1 ////////
        /* Parte síncrona */
        database.count1("es1", combi.getES1(), new RetrollamadaContInterface() {
            @Override
            public void onContObtenido(int n6) {
                /* Parte asíncrona */
                numMax6.put(combi.getES1(), n6);
                posiciones.put(6, numMax6);
                Log.d(TAG, "Posicion: " + n6);
            }
        });

        ////////// ES2 ////////
        /* Parte síncrona */
        database.count1("es2", combi.getES2(), new RetrollamadaContInterface() {
            @Override
            public void onContObtenido(int n7) {
                /* Parte asíncrona */
                numMax7.put(combi.getES2(), n7);
                posiciones.put(7, numMax7);
            }
        });

        n++;

    }
}

public static void actualizaBd() {
    int pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0, pos5 = 0, pos6 = 0, pos7 = 0;
    int cont = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Integer>> posi : posiciones.entrySet()) {
        cont++;
        int clavepos = posi.getKey();
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> num = posi.getValue();
        max = -9999;
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> n : num.entrySet()) {
            int claveN = n.getKey();
            int valor = n.getValue();

            if (clavepos == 1) {
                if (valor > max) {
                    max = valor;
                    pos1 = claveN;
                }
            } else if (clavepos == 2) {
                if (valor > max) {
                    max = valor;
                    pos2 = claveN;
                }
            } else if (clavepos == 3) {
                if (valor > max) {
                    max = valor;
                    pos3 = claveN;
                }
            } else if (clavepos == 4) {
                if (valor > max) {
                    max = valor;
                    pos4 = claveN;
                }
            } else if (clavepos == 5) {
                if (valor > max) {
                    max = valor;
                    pos5 = claveN;
                }
            } else if (clavepos == 6) {
                if (valor > max) {
                    max = valor;
                    pos6 = claveN;
                }
            } else if (clavepos == 7) {
                if (valor > max) {
                    max = valor;
                    pos7 = claveN;
                }
            }
        } // for

    } // for
    actualiza(pos1, pos2, pos3, pos4, pos5, pos6, pos7);

    MainActivity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Pero el `HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Integer>> posiciones` no se puede utilizar mas allá de la interfaz creada, no se puede usar en el método `actualizaBd()`.
Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes empezar a pensar de manera asíncrona o no secuencial para dar solución a tu problema.

En una ejecución asíncrona de consultas (ya sea a una base de datos, servicio web, etc) los resultados pueden llegar en cualquier momento y en cualquier orden. La ejecución del código no espera a la finalización de la consulta y, particularmente en Android, no debe hacerse para evitar bloquear el hilo de la interfaz de usuario (aparecería el típico mensaje "la aplicación no responde, esperar o cerrar").

### Analizando la parte síncrona y asíncrona

Debes reestructurar tu código para hacer el trabajo correctamente:

```
////////// N1 ////////
/* Parte síncrona */
int n1 = database.count1("N1", combi.getN1());
/* Parte asíncrona */
numMax1.put(combi.getN1(), n1);
posiciones.put(1, numMax1);
```

¿Qué es la parte síncrona? La parte en la que tú solicitas la información en el orden que deseas.

¿Qué es la parte asíncrona? La parte en la que se utiliza el valor que se devolverá en un momento dado en un orden indeterminado.

Es decir, no puedes hacer uso del resultado de `database.count1()` hasta que éste haya sido devuelto, por lo que hay que analizar qué es lo que hacemos con el resultado:

- Llamamos a una función (`combi.getN1()`, `combi.getN2()`, etc).
- Agregamos a un `HashMap` un valor (`numMax1`, `numMax2`, etc).
- Agregamos al `HashMap` llamado `posiciones` un valor con una posición (`1` a `numMax1`, `2` a `numMax2`, etc).

Debes recordar que al finalizar la llamada a `actualizarCombiAJugar()` las consultas aún se están ejecutando y los resultados no han sido almacenados en su lugar.

Y, lo más importante, que se irán agregando en el orden en el que se vayan resolviendo, por lo que si necesitas que guarden un orden específico deberás indicar cuál.

---

### Delegando el trabajo a la parte asíncrona

Podrías trasladar el código a la parte asíncrona, pero deberías agregar complejidad al código para pasar a `cont()` todos aquellos datos que se necesitan para realizar el trabajo (todo lo anteriormente expuesto).

Quizá lo más sencillo sería introducir únicamente un nuevo parámetro. Este parámetro será una retrollamada que ejecutará el código deseado una vez obtenido el dato.

Para ello primero deberemos definir la interfaz de la retrollamada:

```
interface RetrollamadaContInterface {
    void onContObtenido(int cont);
}
```

Tras eso podremos hacer eso de ella de la siguiente manera:

```
////////// N1 ////////
/* Parte síncrona */
database.count1("N1", combi.getN1(), new RetrollamadaContInterface() {
    @Override
    public void onContObtenido(int n1) {
        /* Parte asíncrona */
        numMax1.put(combi.getN1(), n1);
        posiciones.put(1, numMax1);
    }
});
```

Ahora deberemos cambiar `cont()` para recibir esa retrollamada y llamarla cuando obtenga el valor de `cont`:

```
public static void count1(String num, int n, RetrollamadaContInterface retrollamada) {
    db.collection("combinaciones")
    .whereEqualTo(num, n)
    .get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            Map<String, Object> comb = new HashMap<>();

            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                int cont = 0;
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    contador = document.getData();
                    cont++;//devolver esta variable
                }
                /* Aquí, en vez de devolver "cont" llamaremos a la retrollamada con su valor */
                retrollamada.onContObtenido(cont);
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
    /* Aquí nunca tendríamos acceso a la variable "cont" */
}
```

Comment: Claro, pero lo que quiero es ir añadiendo el resultado de cont en un map, para mas tarde, una vez ese map se haya llenado, operar con el en otro método, entonces si utilizo la forma que has expuesto creando un método para procesar el valor, almacenaré el valor en un map que llamaremos array, pero cuando se salga de este método y vuelva al método "actualizarCombiAJugar" y este llame de nuevo a "count1", ¿el valor dentro de array se habrá ido, no?  Gracias.

Comment: Depende de donde hayas definido ese mapa de valores. Tal y como te puse al principio de la respuesta, este tipo de propiedades deben definirse a nivel de clase, para que mantenga su valor entre llamadas. ¿Puedes compartir la clase entera para indicarte exactamente dónde debes colocarlo?

Comment: Vale, lo pongo en una respuesta porque aquí no cabe.  Gracias.

Comment: ¿En qué tipo de `HashMap` quieres almacenar los resultados? ¿Quieres guardar los resultados en un `HashMap<String, Integer>` que asocie los parámetros de entrada a la función `count` con el resultado de la consulta?

Comment: El resultado del método `count1` lo almaceno en un 'HashMap<Integer, Integer>', que a su vez almaceno en un 'HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Integer>>'.

Comment: Ok, entonces almacenaré el resultado allí. Estoy fuera de casa, hasta dentro de unas 3 horas no estaré disponible.

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta con el código que has indicado pero no se puede usar el `HashMap` mas allá de la interfaz.

Comment: Ok, ya veo que todo se llama desde `readData` llamando de manera secuencial a ambas funciones. Pero tienes que tener en cuenta que **no puedes acceder a la información del `HashMap` hasta que todos los resultados hayan sido devueltos**. En ese caso, debes esperar a que todos finalicen antes de llamar a `actualizaBd`. Eso imagino que sabes hacerlo, ¿no?.

Comment: Me imagino que será durmiendo el hilo, pero no se como hacerlo.

Comment: Puedes hacer una nueva pregunta para preguntar cómo esperar o detectar que varios procesos que se ejecutan de fondo han finalizado. Cuando la redactes pásame el enlace en este comentario o avísame para que le eche un vistazo.

Comment: Ya está redactada, gracias, este es el enlace: [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/478915/c%c3%b3mo-esperar-a-varios-procesos-ejecutados-de-fondo)