# Cómo esperar a varios procesos ejecutados de fondo

Tags: java, android

En el proyecto se ejecutan varios procesos asíncronos en el método `actualizarCombiAJugar()` y quiero recoger esos datos en un `HashMap<>posiciones` para utilizarlo en el método `actualizaBd()`.

Para poder utilizarlo necesito esperar a que termine la ejecución de estos procesos pero no sé cómo hacerlo.

Éste es el código que lanza las llamadas asíncronas a través del método `count1()`:

```
public static void actualizarCombiAJugar() {
    // database.dameCombinaciones();
    Map<Integer, Map<String, Object>> cursor = combi;


    HashMap<Integer, Integer> numMax1 = new HashMap();
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> numMax2 = new HashMap();
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> numMax3 = new HashMap();
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> numMax4 = new HashMap();
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> numMax5 = new HashMap();
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> numMax6 = new HashMap();
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> numMax7 = new HashMap();
    int n = 0;

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Map<String, Object>> c : cursor.entrySet()) {
        combinacion combi = new combinacion();

        combi.setN1(Math.toIntExact((Long) c.getValue().get("n1")));
        combi.setN2(Math.toIntExact((Long) c.getValue().get("n2")));
        combi.setN3(Math.toIntExact((Long) c.getValue().get("n3")));
        combi.setN4(Math.toIntExact((Long) c.getValue().get("n4")));
        combi.setN5(Math.toIntExact((Long) c.getValue().get("n5")));
        combi.setES1(Math.toIntExact((Long) c.getValue().get("es1")));
        combi.setES2(Math.toIntExact((Long) c.getValue().get("es2")));

        ////////// N1 ////////
        /* Parte síncrona */
        database.count1("N1", combi.getN1(), new RetrollamadaContInterface() {
            @Override
            public void onContObtenido(int n1) {
                /* Parte asíncrona */
                numMax1.put(combi.getN1(), n1);
                posiciones.put(1, numMax1);
            }
        });

        ////////// N2 ////////
        /* Parte síncrona */
        database.count1("N2", combi.getN2(), new RetrollamadaContInterface() {
            @Override
            public void onContObtenido(int n2) {
                /* Parte asíncrona */
                numMax2.put(combi.getN2(), n2);
                posiciones.put(2, numMax2);
            }
        });

        ////////// N3 ////////
        /* Parte síncrona */
        database.count1("N3", combi.getN3(), new RetrollamadaContInterface() {
            @Override
            public void onContObtenido(int n3) {
                /* Parte asíncrona */
                numMax3.put(combi.getN3(), n3);
                posiciones.put(3, numMax3);
            }
        });

        ////////// N4 ////////
        /* Parte síncrona */
        database.count1("N4", combi.getN4(), new RetrollamadaContInterface() {
            @Override
            public void onContObtenido(int n4) {
                /* Parte asíncrona */
                numMax4.put(combi.getN4(), n4);
                posiciones.put(4, numMax4);
            }
        });

        ////////// N5 ////////
        /* Parte síncrona */
        database.count1("N5", combi.getN5(), new RetrollamadaContInterface() {
            @Override
            public void onContObtenido(int n5) {
                /* Parte asíncrona */
                numMax5.put(combi.getN5(), n5);
                posiciones.put(5, numMax5);
            }
        });

        ////////// ES1 ////////
        /* Parte síncrona */
        database.count1("es1", combi.getES1(), new RetrollamadaContInterface() {
            @Override
            public void onContObtenido(int n6) {
                /* Parte asíncrona */
                numMax6.put(combi.getES1(), n6);
                posiciones.put(6, numMax6);
                Log.d(TAG, "Posicion: " + n6);
            }
        });

        ////////// ES2 ////////
        /* Parte síncrona */
        database.count1("es2", combi.getES2(), new RetrollamadaContInterface() {
            @Override
            public void onContObtenido(int n7) {
                /* Parte asíncrona */
                numMax7.put(combi.getES2(), n7);
                posiciones.put(7, numMax7);
            }
        });

        n++;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

public static void actualizaBd() {
    int pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0, pos5 = 0, pos6 = 0, pos7 = 0;
    int cont = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Integer>> posi : posiciones.entrySet()) {
        cont++;
        int clavepos = posi.getKey();
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> num = posi.getValue();
        max = -9999;
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> n : num.entrySet()) {
            int claveN = n.getKey();
            int valor = n.getValue();

            if (clavepos == 1) {
                if (valor > max) {
                    max = valor;
                    pos1 = claveN;
                }
            } else if (clavepos == 2) {
                if (valor > max) {
                    max = valor;
                    pos2 = claveN;
                }
            } else if (clavepos == 3) {
                if (valor > max) {
                    max = valor;
                    pos3 = claveN;
                }
            } else if (clavepos == 4) {
                if (valor > max) {
                    max = valor;
                    pos4 = claveN;
                }
            } else if (clavepos == 5) {
                if (valor > max) {
                    max = valor;
                    pos5 = claveN;
                }
            } else if (clavepos == 6) {
                if (valor > max) {
                    max = valor;
                    pos6 = claveN;
                }
            } else if (clavepos == 7) {
                if (valor > max) {
                    max = valor;
                    pos7 = claveN;
                }
            }
        } // for

    } // for
    actualiza(pos1, pos2, pos3, pos4, pos5, pos6, pos7);

    MainActivity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Ésta es la clase completa:

```
public class database {
Context context;
static FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
static final Map<Integer, Map<String, Object>> combi = new HashMap<>();
static Map<String, Object> contador = new HashMap<>();
public static HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Integer>> posiciones = new HashMap();
public static int max = -9999;
private static DatabaseReference dbCombi;
public ArrayList<combinacion> array = new ArrayList<>();


public database(@Nullable Context context) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
}


public void inicializarCombPosibles(combinacion comb) {
    db.collection("comb_posibles")
            .document("combGana")
            .set(comb);
}

public void inicializarCombinaciones(combinacion comb) {
    db.collection("combinaciones")
            .add(comb);
            /*.set(/*new combinacion(2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), SetOptions.merge()comb
            );*/
}


public void dameCombinacionGanadora() {
    dbCombi = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("comb_posibles");
    dbCombi.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);

    /*DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("comb_posibles").document("combGana");
    docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                if (document.exists()) {
                    data = document.getData();
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
                }

            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
            }
        }

    });*/
}

ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        //  MainActivity.array.clear();
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            for (DataSnapshot snap : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                combinacion comb = snap.getValue(combinacion.class);
                //MainActivity.array.add(comb);
            }
            MainActivity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

    }
};

private static void mostrarData(MainAdapter.ViewHolder holder, Map<String, Object> c) {
    combinacion combina = new combinacion();
    combina.setN1(Math.toIntExact((Long) c.get("n1")));
    combina.setN2(Math.toIntExact((Long) c.get("n2")));
    combina.setN3(Math.toIntExact((Long) c.get("n3")));
    combina.setN4(Math.toIntExact((Long) c.get("n4")));
    combina.setN5(Math.toIntExact((Long) c.get("n5")));
    combina.setES1(Math.toIntExact((Long) c.get("es1")));
    combina.setES2(Math.toIntExact((Long) c.get("es2")));

    MainAdapter.personalizaVista(holder, combina);
}

public static void dameCombinaciones() {
    db.collection("combinaciones")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {

                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        int cont = 0;
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {

                            Map<String, Object> data = document.getData();
                            combi.put(cont, data);
                            Log.w(TAG, "Bucle", task.getException());
                            cont++;

                        }
                        readData(combi);
                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
}

private static void readData(Map<Integer, Map<String, Object>> combi) {
    actualizarCombiAJugar();
    actualizaBd();
}

public static void actualizarCombiAJugar() {
    // database.dameCombinaciones();
    Map<Integer, Map<String, Object>> cursor = combi;


    HashMap<Integer, Integer> numMax1 = new HashMap();
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> numMax2 = new HashMap();
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> numMax3 = new HashMap();
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> numMax4 = new HashMap();
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> numMax5 = new HashMap();
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> numMax6 = new HashMap();
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> numMax7 = new HashMap();
    int n = 0;

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Map<String, Object>> c : cursor.entrySet()) {
        combinacion combi = new combinacion();

        combi.setN1(Math.toIntExact((Long) c.getValue().get("n1")));
        combi.setN2(Math.toIntExact((Long) c.getValue().get("n2")));
        combi.setN3(Math.toIntExact((Long) c.getValue().get("n3")));
        combi.setN4(Math.toIntExact((Long) c.getValue().get("n4")));
        combi.setN5(Math.toIntExact((Long) c.getValue().get("n5")));
        combi.setES1(Math.toIntExact((Long) c.getValue().get("es1")));
        combi.setES2(Math.toIntExact((Long) c.getValue().get("es2")));

        ////////// N1 ////////
        /* Parte síncrona */
        database.count1("N1", combi.getN1(), new RetrollamadaContInterface() {
            @Override
            public void onContObtenido(int n1) {
                /* Parte asíncrona */
                numMax1.put(combi.getN1(), n1);
                posiciones.put(1, numMax1);
            }
        });

        ////////// N2 ////////
        /* Parte síncrona */
        database.count1("N2", combi.getN2(), new RetrollamadaContInterface() {
            @Override
            public void onContObtenido(int n2) {
                /* Parte asíncrona */
                numMax2.put(combi.getN2(), n2);
                posiciones.put(2, numMax2);
            }
        });

        ////////// N3 ////////
        /* Parte síncrona */
        database.count1("N3", combi.getN3(), new RetrollamadaContInterface() {
            @Override
            public void onContObtenido(int n3) {
                /* Parte asíncrona */
                numMax3.put(combi.getN3(), n3);
                posiciones.put(3, numMax3);
            }
        });

        ////////// N4 ////////
        /* Parte síncrona */
        database.count1("N4", combi.getN4(), new RetrollamadaContInterface() {
            @Override
            public void onContObtenido(int n4) {
                /* Parte asíncrona */
                numMax4.put(combi.getN4(), n4);
                posiciones.put(4, numMax4);
            }
        });

        ////////// N5 ////////
        /* Parte síncrona */
        database.count1("N5", combi.getN5(), new RetrollamadaContInterface() {
            @Override
            public void onContObtenido(int n5) {
                /* Parte asíncrona */
                numMax5.put(combi.getN5(), n5);
                posiciones.put(5, numMax5);
            }
        });

        ////////// ES1 ////////
        /* Parte síncrona */
        database.count1("es1", combi.getES1(), new RetrollamadaContInterface() {
            @Override
            public void onContObtenido(int n6) {
                /* Parte asíncrona */
                numMax6.put(combi.getES1(), n6);
                posiciones.put(6, numMax6);
                Log.d(TAG, "Posicion: " + n6);
            }
        });

        ////////// ES2 ////////
        /* Parte síncrona */
        database.count1("es2", combi.getES2(), new RetrollamadaContInterface() {
            @Override
            public void onContObtenido(int n7) {
                /* Parte asíncrona */
                numMax7.put(combi.getES2(), n7);
                posiciones.put(7, numMax7);
            }
        });

        n++;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

public static void actualizaBd() {
    int pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0, pos5 = 0, pos6 = 0, pos7 = 0;
    int cont = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Integer>> posi : posiciones.entrySet()) {
        cont++;
        int clavepos = posi.getKey();
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> num = posi.getValue();
        max = -9999;
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> n : num.entrySet()) {
            int claveN = n.getKey();
            int valor = n.getValue();

            if (clavepos == 1) {
                if (valor > max) {
                    max = valor;
                    pos1 = claveN;
                }
            } else if (clavepos == 2) {
                if (valor > max) {
                    max = valor;
                    pos2 = claveN;
                }
            } else if (clavepos == 3) {
                if (valor > max) {
                    max = valor;
                    pos3 = claveN;
                }
            } else if (clavepos == 4) {
                if (valor > max) {
                    max = valor;
                    pos4 = claveN;
                }
            } else if (clavepos == 5) {
                if (valor > max) {
                    max = valor;
                    pos5 = claveN;
                }
            } else if (clavepos == 6) {
                if (valor > max) {
                    max = valor;
                    pos6 = claveN;
                }
            } else if (clavepos == 7) {
                if (valor > max) {
                    max = valor;
                    pos7 = claveN;
                }
            }
        } // for

    } // for
    actualiza(pos1, pos2, pos3, pos4, pos5, pos6, pos7);

    MainActivity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public static void actualiza(int pos1, int pos2, int pos3, int pos4, int pos5, int pos6, int pos7) {
    DocumentReference dR = db.collection("comb_posibles").document("combGana");
    dR.update("n1", pos1, "n2", pos2, "n3", pos3, "n4", pos4, "n5", pos5, "es1", pos6, "es2", pos7)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully updated!");
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Error updating document", e);
                }
            });
}

public static void contarCombinaciones(VisualizarCombinacionesActivity vCA) {
    db.collection("combinaciones")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    List<Object> data = new ArrayList<>();
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        int cont = 0;
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            data.add(document.getData());
                            cont++;
                        }
                        vCA.adaptador(cont, data);
                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
}

public static void count1(String num, int n, RetrollamadaContInterface retrollamada) {
    db.collection("combinaciones")
            .whereEqualTo(num, n)
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    Map<String, Object> comb = new HashMap<>();

                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        int cont = 0;
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            contador = document.getData();
                            cont++;//devolver esta variable
                        }
                        
                        retrollamada.onContObtenido(cont);
                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
    
}



public void insertar(combinacion combi) {
    db.collection("combinaciones")
            .add(combi);
}
}
```

Comment: No puedes decidir cuando acaban los procesos asincronos, tampoco se ve donde invocas al método actualizaBd(), así que es complicado ver como lo usas y si se está invocando adecudamente,

Comment: He editado la pregunta con la clase entera, llamo al método ```actualizaBd()``` en ```readData()```.  Gracias.

Comment: Genial! Con ViewModel, se pueden poner observadores de hilos, te aconsejo usarlo, es muy práctico. Por otra parte te diría que añadas el método de guardar en BBDD dentro de la operación asíncrona, para que cuando acabe, guarde los datos, ahora mismo no se me ocurre ninguna otra forma de hacerlo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existen varios métodos para lanzar una batería de procesos en segundo plano y esperar a que éstos terminen.

Una de las soluciones podría ser analizar el contenido de los `HashMap` que reciben los datos para averiguar cuándo han llegado al número de elementos esperado, pero podrían producirse condiciones de carrera que impidieran que el último actualizara la base de datos, o bien que los últimos hicieran múltiples actualizaciones.

Otra solución muy sencilla podría ser hacer uso de [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html).

Esta clase te permite gestionar un contador entero que puede ser modificado fácilmente controlando correctamente [los problemas que puede acarrear la concurrencia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computaci%C3%B3n_concurrente).

Para empezar podrías definir una propiedad a nivel de clase para ello:

```
public class database {
    /* ... */
    public ArrayList<combinacion> array = new ArrayList<>();
    AtomicInteger procesos = new AtomicInteger();
```

Tras eso basta con incrementar su contenido en uno cada vez que realicemos una petición y decrementarlo en uno cada vez que finalizamos una tarea.

La parte importante es decrementar el contenido y para eso se nos proporciona un método que nos permite modificar y obtener el valor actual.

Podríamos modificar el código de la siguiente manera para gestionar el número de procesos que quedan pendientes de finalizar su trabajo:

```
public static void count1(String num, int n, RetrollamadaContInterface retrollamada) {
    /* Incrementamos en uno las tareas que quedarán en segundo plano */
    Log.v("CONCURRENCIA", "(+) Procesos: " + procesos.incrementAndGet());
    db.collection("combinaciones")
    .whereEqualTo(num, n)
    .get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            Map<String, Object> comb = new HashMap<>();

            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                int cont = 0;
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    contador = document.getData();
                    cont++;//devolver esta variable
                }
                        
                retrollamada.onContObtenido(cont);
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
            }
            /* Decrementamos el número de procesos en segundo plano */
            int numero = procesos.decrementAndGet();
            Log.v("CONCURRENCIA", "(-) Procesos: " + numero);
            /* Si era el último, actualizamos la base de datos */
            if (numero == 0) {
                actualizaBd();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

De esta manera cada inicio de la consulta, ANTES de realizar la consulta, irá sumando uno al contenido de `procesos` y cada finalización de la consulta irá restando uno al contenido de `procesos`, DESPUÉS de haber llamado a la retrollamada, de manera que cuando dicho contador llegue a `0` se considera que no queda ningún proceso en segundo plano pendiente, siendo ese el momento de actualizar la base de datos.

Como hemos delegado la escritura en la base de datos a la finalización de los procesos en segundo plano, deberemos llamar únicamente a `actualizarCombiAJugar()` dentro del método `readData()`.

---

PD: Fíjate que decremento el valor de `procesos` haya finalizado bien o no la consulta (`task.isSuccessful()`).

Deberías gestionar el caso de que una de ellas falle para repetirla o bien cancelar la actualización de la base de datos. Una forma sencilla de cancelar la actualización de la base de datos en este caso podría ser asignar un valor negativo a `procesos` con `procesos.set(-1)`.

De esta manera nunca llegaría a `0` y, por lo tanto, nunca se llamaría a `actualizaBd()` cuando finalizaran el resto de consultas.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha funcionado.

Comment: Me alegra mucho que te haya funcionado. Te recomiendo que intentes reutilizar el código lo máximo posible. Por ejemplo, implementar un único `combi.set(n, ...)` en vez de `combi.setN1()`, `combi.setN2()`, etc. También con las variables `pos[n]` en vez de `pos1`, `pos2`, etc. De esa manera todo podrás resolverlo con bucles y no repitiendo código.

Comment: Si, a partir de ahora me dedicaré a mejorar el código. Gracias.